# TFS - Create a branch from local working copy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I am trying to create a branch from my local workspace of a checked-out project.

Basic background:
I checked out from the 'trunk' of a project and made a lot of changes.
I now want to check these changes into a new branch.

I created a new branch from within Source Control - but my workspace is still mapped to the trunk.

I followed the steps from an article I found here: [Branch from local workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728318/branch-from-local-workspace)

So I shelved my changes.
Created a branch.
Used TFPT to migrate from the trunk to the branch

```
tfpt unshelve "My uncomplete changes" /source:"$/MyRoot/MyProject-Trunk" /target:"$/MyRoot/MyProject-Branch"
```

Everything looked to go smoothly (except it doesn't seem to support files which have been renamed - so I had to skip them)

But nothing has changed.
The branch is an exact duplicate of the trunk (no local changes included)
My workspace is still mapped to the trunk.
If I check-in, it checks into the trunk.

I tried to unmap the checked-out version I have, delete the local files, then check out the branch, then unshelve the changes I made, but I am flooded with

```
No appropriate mapping exists for $/Root/MyProject/Myfile.cs
```

It seems so simple, but TFS seems to add an extra layer of complexity to what was such an easy task in SVN...
Hopefully something stupid I am doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. You need to include the new branch in your workspace in order to see any changes (otherwise you'll only see the checked-in versions). From `Source Control Explorer`, select `Workspace->Workspaces...` from the toolbar.
2. Select `Edit` for your workspace and add a mapping to your new branch, e.g.
   `Active|$/Root/MyProject-Branch|<My Local TFS Storage>\MyProject-Branch`
3. Run the command `tfpt unshelve <shelveset> /migrate /source:$/Root/MyProject /target:$/Root/MyProject-Branch`. It should create a new shelveset with mappings changed to your new branch.
4. Try unshelving the new, migrated shelveset onto your new branch.

Btw, in TFS the term is to *map* a project/branch to a local storage, not 'check out' as in SVN. That term is used for those files you make changes to ;).