# Create branch from local directory after it was destroyed in our TFS repository

Tags: tfs, data-recovery, tfvc

We accidentally destroyed a branch from our TFS server.

is there a way to create a new branch from the local files on my computer?

I looked into those 2 solutions:

- [TFS - Create a branch from local working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907654/tfs-create-a-branch-from-local-working-copy)
- [Branch from local workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728318/branch-from-local-workspace)

But I don't think that I can use them since my changes are not shelved

Basically I think I need to create a new branch and overwrite it with a local directory. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you delete not destroy the branch? If so, you could just simply recover the branch instead of create a new one.

Comment: we destroyed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can start from a fresh folder

- Map the parent folder to a new local workspace
- create the folder you want to use as branch root in your local workspace.
- Copy the contents from your local backup.
- Check in the folder.
- In the source control explorer use the Convert Folder to Branch option.
- From the commandline perform a baseless merge with the original parent folder `tf merge /baseless $/project/revivedfolder $/project/parentbranch /recursive /force`
- Resolve all conflicts (this is potentially going to be a lot of work)
- Check in the complete the restore process.

If you have a previous changeset that's similar enough to the destroyed branch (e.g. the changeset that was used to originally create the destroyed branch, or the changeset of the last successful merge from this branch), you could also use the following technique:

- Branch a new branch from the parent from the changeset the now deleted branch was created from or last merged with.
- Map the new branch folder to a new local workspace and get latest
- Locally delete all files in the new local workspace (this is to ensure deleted files will stay deleted)
- Paste your changed files over the branch. Be careful with renames, these may get lost. You can resolve them from the Team Explorer window. See: [Fix the outcome after you rename an item in your operating system](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders#rename-an-item-in-tfvc).
- Check in the files in your local workspace.
- Because the branch was created from the parent branch, the merge relationship will be present without performing a baseless merge.

**Support option** If the branch was deleted recently it may still exist in the TFS database, the cleanup job doesn't run immediately unless you've told it to. By contacting Microsoft Support you may be able to revive the deleted content including all history.

Answer (score 2):

First, please make sure you or your teammates haven't destroyed this branch (After doing this, there is no way to recover it in TFS server).

### If you delete this branch in Visual Studio,

> ***To restore an item deleted from the server***
>
> From the menu bar choose **Tools, Options**.
>
> On the **Options** dialog box, navigate to **Source Control, Visual
>   Studio Team Foundation Server.**
>
> Select **Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer**, and then
>   choose **OK**.
>
> From the menu bar choose **View**, **Other Windows, Source Control
>   Explorer.**
>
> In Source Control Explorer, navigate to the folder that contains the
>   item you want to restore.
>
> Open the item’s context menu (select the item and right-click it) and
>   then choose **Undelete**.

### If you delete this branch from your dev machine outside of Visual Studio,

Please check the solution from  MSDN link [Delete or restore files and folders](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders)

---

If you  got the options gray(not available) such as below screenshot

[image]

***Note:*** To be able to undelete a branch you must first **map the parent folder/branch to your workspace**. Now, the undelete option will be enable.

Comment: Unfortunately i think our IT destroyed it  since i don't see it as deleted.
but thx for the help. ill update the question

Comment: Hi @Dardar Please double confirm this, usually a person will not accidentally  destroy files in tfs source control. To see the deleted files you need to **Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer**, detail ways please refer this thread: http://pinter.org/archives/1455

Comment: @Dardar If your IT really destroy the branch, below step may do the trick: delete the old workspace ,back up your local files. create a new empty folder in TFS server, create a new workspace , map the empty folder with the local , move local files to the empty folder, check in all pending changes. Covert the folder to a branch.

Comment: @MrHinsh No, ill-conceived. OP still need to perform a baseless merge, just the same behavior as creating a new branch.